# how to use find count using raw method in query builder on laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to find count of gender using the raw statement but i get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$total' (T_VARIABLE). Can someone please tell me whats my error

```
$collection='{gender:"Male"}'                    
$total = DB::collection('leads')->raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->find();
});
return  $total;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon is missing behind `$collection='{gender:"Male"}'`. (that should at least solve the error you get currently)